# Any Ideas how to make a Python program that makes simple commands into the OS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program that sort of like open a certain software from my PC and just do simple button clicks whatsoever. How could I do this?

Comment: By the way, what you are describing *simple commands into the os*. That is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2.7//library/os.html#os.system) to open the app. If you want better control use subprocess. After that, you could use [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make the clicks. Look at that [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here is an example:

```py
import os
os.system("<location-to-your-exe>")
```

Then you could use pyautogui to move the mouse and click:

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.move(-30, 0) 
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: I just knew about this concept about python to be honest, I will study this API in the meantime. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out python modules pyautogui, keyboard.
other key press thing:
https://pythonprogramming.net/direct-input-game-python-plays-gta-v/?completed=/open-cv-basics-python-plays-gta-v/

bring window to front:
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/

Comment: I dunno what this is downvoted for. Those are literally the things I use to navigate automating window clicks, typing, and manipulation programs that are intended for manual human use on my machines.

Comment: You cool. I figured it was someone tryin to police.